# How to: Autohotkey Com - Excel PasteSpecial()

Tags: excel, com, autohotkey

Currently trying to use PasteSpecial but having some type of syntax issues.
Either get COM error: "Unable to get paste special property of the range class.", or it does not paste from the clipboard.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
Data := Clipboard

Xl := ComObjCreate("Excel.Application") 
Xl := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")

filepath = %A_WorkingDir%\new.xlsx
Xl.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
Xl.Visible := True
Clipboard := Data

; tried these get COM error mentioned above ;

Xl.Selection.PasteSpecial(-4163)
Xl.Range("A:D").PasteSpecial(-4163)  
Xl.Selection.Range("A:D").PasteSpecial(-4163) 
Xl.Range("A:D").Selection.PasteSpecial(-4163) 
Xl.Selection.PasteSpecial(-4163).Range("A:D")
Xl.Selection.Range("A:D") := XL.Selection.PasteSpecial(-4163)
Xl.ActiveSheet.Selection.PasteSpecial(-4163)

; tried these no COM error mentioned above but does not paste ;

ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial(-4163)
Selection.PasteSpecial(-4163)
ActiveSheet.Selection.PasteSpecial(-4163)
Selection.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial(-4163)
ActiveSheet.Range("A:D").PasteSpecial(-4163)
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial(-4163).Range("A:D") 
ActiveSheet.Selection.PasteSpecial(-4163).Range("A:D")
ActiveSheet.Selection.Range("A:D").PasteSpecial(-4163)
ActiveSheet.Range("A:D").Selection.PasteSpecial(-4163)
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: From the AHK forum someone showed me that: `Xl.ActiveSheet.Range("A:D").PasteSpecial()`  works, despite -4163 being described as the values on paste mode.  On the other hand, this will also paste formatting so one would need to figure a way to work around that, easily done with Notepad.  I will leave the question open in hopes that someone will figure out how to do values only.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this can be accomplished in a much simpler fashion.

You can open the Paste Special dialog in Excel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. From there, you simply hit the [corresponding letter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Paste-Special-options-c31b7c9e-69ce-4b60-8c3a-dc5ea10d872c) for whatever setting you want and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the clipboard's contents will paste in the desired format.

Following that thread, here's an example:

```
pasteSpecial(mode){
replace := {"All":"a","all":"a","Formulas":"f","formulas":"f","Values":"v","values":"v","Formats":"t","formats":"t","Comments":"c","comments":"c","Validation":"n","validation":"n"}
For start, end in replace {
    StringReplace, mode, mode, %start%, %end%, All
}
SendInput, {Ctrl down}{Alt down}{v down}{Ctrl up}{Alt up}{v up}
WinWait, Paste Special
WinGetTitle, Title, A
if (RegExMatch(Title, "Paste Special"))
{
SendInput, %mode%{Enter}
}}

F3::
pasteSpecial("Values")
return
```

Here you've got a function that'll parse the string input, and replace the upper/lowercase version with the keyboard shortcut. This will allow a bit more control than just coding specifically for Paste Values.

Answer (score 0):

`Xl.Range("A:D").PasteSpecial(-4163)`
Works fine as long as you make a copy which has the correct properties for the paste to understand.

Example:
`Xl.Range("E:H").Copy ;Copy of the excel range which has the correct properties for next stage.
Xl.Range("A:D").PasteSpecial(-4163) ;Paste the value without formatting`